Does convex set in $R^3$ include origin if it has points with zero coordinates for each dimension in both Octant (+,+,+) and Octant (-,-,-)? In $R^4$?
A convex set in $R^n$ is known to have at least one point with zero coordinate for each dimension while all other coordinates of these points are non-negative, and at least one point with zero coordinate for each dimension while all other coordinates of these points are non-positive, we want to find if under these constraints the set always includes origin. We note that definition of the problem doesn’t imply that we have $2n$ different points, some of them can coincide, if all of them coincide and set satisfies constraints above, the only point that set is known to have is origin.
In $R^1$ and in $R^2$ the statement means that set has at least one non-negative and at least one non-positive point on $x-$axis, which implies that origin is included in this set.
Prove this statement or find counterexample in $R^{3+}$

Picture 1 below shows $R^3$ case when we have $3$ points A,C,E in Octant (+,+,+) and $3$ points B,D,F in Octant (-,-,-). A and B are in XY-plane, C and D are in ZY-plane, E and F are in XZ-plane (some of these points may coincide). Interval AB intersects positive Y-axis or positive X-axis or includes origin, lets assume it intersects positive Y-axis at point G. Interval ED intersects XY-plane in H, which has non-negative X-coordinate and non-positive Y-coordinate. Interval HG intersects non-negative X-axis at point I. Similarly if AB intersects positive X-axis we use interval CF instead of ED and its intersection with XY-plane to show that there are points G,I on non-negative Y-axis and non-negative X-axis belonging to convex set. In the same way we prove that there are such points on non-positive Y-axis and non-positive X-axis, which completes the prove of statement for $R^3$ case.

Picture 2 below shows $R^4$ case, if we consider 4 points A(0,0,-1,0), B(0,-1,0,0), C(1,0,0,0), D(0,0,0,1), (points A,B,C are shown in XYZ space), we can see that our statement is satisfied by convex hull of these points, indeed, points D,D,D,C have all non-negative coordinates while having among them points with each of four coordinates with zero values, points A,A,B,A have all non-positive coordinates while having among them points with each of four coordinates with zero values, but the convex hull of these four points does not include origin, we can see this as any point in convex hull is a convex combination of some point inside triangle ABC and point D, which always have some non-zero coordinate. This example proves that statement is wrong for $R^4$ case and for all $R^{4+}$ cases as we can add zero coordinates to our example in $R^4$ to obtain counterexample for $R^{4+}$ case.

